# Free Linked-List In C

Tags: c, linked-list, free

Hi I need help freeing my Linked List in C. When I run this code I get a seg fault 11. Everything up to the freeing works perfectly. Thank you for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void){
    struct node *root, *next;

    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root -> x = 0;
    root -> next = NULL;

    next = root;

    for (int i = 0; i <=10; i++){
        next -> next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        next -> x = i;
        next = next -> next;
    }

    next = root;

    for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j ++){
        printf("%i", next -> x);
        next = next -> next;
    }
        next = root;

    while(next != NULL){
        next = root;
        root = root -> next;
        free(next);
    }
    free(root);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The original code has a few issues:

1) The `while(next != NULL)` loop tries to use already freed node.

2) The loop already takes care of the releasing `root` (`next = root;`) so there is no need to release `root` separately.

3) In order for `while` loop to work properly the `tail`/`head` of the list has to be properly `NULL` terminated. (I have added that termination in the first `for` loop)

4) Second loop is supposed to print all `x` values. It did not. The counter was short by one number.

The improved variation of the program is presented below. Please check the program output as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int x;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void){
    struct node *root, *next, *to_free;

    root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));                   // 1 malloc

    root->x = 777;
    root->next = NULL;

    printf("allocating memory for root. root->x = %i\n\n", root-> x);

    next = root; // next points to "head" (root)

    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
        next->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));      // 11 mallocs

        printf("allocating memory for next. next->x = %i\n", i+1 );   

        next->next->x = i+1;                           //

        next = next->next;
        next->next = NULL;                             // list termination is needed!
    }
    printf("\n");

    next = root; // next points to "head" (root)

    for (int j = 0; j <= 11; j ++){                   // 12 nodes has to be printed! 
        printf("Printing x = %i\n", next->x);
        next = next->next;
    }
    printf("\n");

    next = root;   //  next points to "head" (root)

    while(next != NULL)         
    {   
        to_free = next;         // we will free `next` as `to_free` soon

        next = next->next;      // move to the next node   

        printf("deallocating node with x = %i\n", to_free->x);

       free(to_free);          // now free the remembered `next`
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
allocating memory for root. root->x = 777

allocating memory for next. next->x = 1
allocating memory for next. next->x = 2
allocating memory for next. next->x = 3
allocating memory for next. next->x = 4
allocating memory for next. next->x = 5
allocating memory for next. next->x = 6
allocating memory for next. next->x = 7
allocating memory for next. next->x = 8
allocating memory for next. next->x = 9
allocating memory for next. next->x = 10
allocating memory for next. next->x = 11

Printing x = 777
Printing x = 1
Printing x = 2
Printing x = 3
Printing x = 4
Printing x = 5
Printing x = 6
Printing x = 7
Printing x = 8
Printing x = 9
Printing x = 10
Printing x = 11

deallocating node with x = 777
deallocating node with x = 1
deallocating node with x = 2
deallocating node with x = 3
deallocating node with x = 4
deallocating node with x = 5
deallocating node with x = 6
deallocating node with x = 7
deallocating node with x = 8
deallocating node with x = 9
deallocating node with x = 10
deallocating node with x = 11
```

Comment: @DMop If you value my help you could upvote my answer and accept it. I would appreciate it. If you need more explanations let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your loop to free the nodes checks to see if `next` is `NULL` *after* it has called `free(next)`.

Comment: I made the first line of the loop to free to be the last line of the same loop and still received the same error. Can you help with this?

Comment: Without seeing how you changed the code, or knowing which `free` is having a problem, not really.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated by the other answer, the `free()` below is in the wrong place, as it frees the memory that is then checked in the condition of the while loop.

```
while(next != NULL){
    root = root->next;
    next = root;
    free(next);
}
```

However also, if move the first statement of that block to the end of the block as you suggested in your comment, your problem is probably the fact that this loop itself is fully sufficient to free the entire list, and so the statement `free(root)` AFTER the loop is likely a double free, which is usually an error. You can delete it.

Comment: I deleted the 2nd free and moved the code as suggested in my comment, but still got the same error. Do you know why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in your code which are listed bellow and the most important one is number 1.

1. The pointer `next` in first item of your list (root) does not point to `NULL`, because it will be changed on the first `for` loop. So `while(next != NULL)` will not work because there is no item in your linked list which points to `NULL`.
2. `malloc` will return pointer with type `void *`, so it is better to cast it to your `next`.
3. After doing memory allocation, the result should be checked, if the memory was allocated successfully or not.
   Also, I would suggest you to use `typedef` for defining your linked list.

Your code should be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node{
    int x;
    struct node *next, *temp;
} node_t;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  node_t *root, *next, *temp;

  root = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if(root == NULL){
    /* Do somthing */
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to allocate memory\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  root -> x = 100;
  root -> next = NULL;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    next = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if(next == NULL){
      /* Do somthing */
      fprintf(stderr, "unable to allocate memory\n");
      exit(1);
    }
    next -> x = i;
    next -> next = root;
    root = next;
  }
  temp = next;
  while(temp != NULL){
    printf("x value is: %d\n", temp -> x);
    temp = temp -> next;
  }

  while(next != NULL){
    temp = next -> next;
    free(next);
    next = temp;
  }
}
```